# RabbitMQ in container app Azure, cant see the UI

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, containers, azure-container-apps

deploy rabbitmq:latest in an azure container app, enable ports 15672;

I can't see the rabbit UI and I don't know why it seems that everything is well displayed.

environment variables added:

```
  -RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
  -RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=user
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which url is used to connect rabbitmq service as through  UI url i am not able to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, it was nonsense.

[image]

[image]

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The `rabbitmq:latest` image is not enabling the `rabbitmq_management` plugin by default. Which only enabled these

```
rabbitmq-1  | 2023-07-14 08:45:41.693192+00:00 [info] <0.599.0>  * rabbitmq_prometheus
rabbitmq-1  | 2023-07-14 08:45:41.693192+00:00 [info] <0.599.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
rabbitmq-1  | 2023-07-14 08:45:41.693192+00:00 [info] <0.599.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent
```

In the [doc](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq)

> There is a second set of tags provided with the management plugin installed and enabled by default, which is available on the standard management port of 15672

So you have to use image `rabbitmq:3-management` for `Management Plugin`

or you can enable RabbitMQ management plugin with the `rabbitmq:latest` image with this `Dockerfile` content

```
FROM rabbitmq:latest

# Enable RabbitMQ management plugin
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

**Note :** Deploy the container app with management image and you will able to access it without mentioning the port `15672` in the url.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, I tried with:
rabbitmq: 3-management


this is my configuration:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS3IH.png --- Container
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpO4P.png ---- Ingress
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMXH4.png --- Revision
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo8Td.png --- dont load page

If I don't see the UI, how can I see if the container is working correctly?

Comment: Did you tried it without :15672 from the url?

Comment: I can see that the url containing `.internal`, which I think the app is not exposed to external usage.

Comment: Hi @DiegoDiaz I am able to see UI through above , however I am not able to connect to rabbitmq server from other microservice using this URL , could  you please help which url you used